# Hierarchical models of software quality

Tags: model, models, hierarchical

Can anyone help me listing the Hierarchical models of software quality? Please can anyone say me

Is it just McCall and Bohem model or many other hierarchical models exists?

Answer (score 0):

There are some others, see:

http://www.sqa.net/softwarequalityattributes.html

and follow the FURPS link

The ISO 9126-1 software quality model identifies 6 main quality characteristics, namely:

- Functionality
- Reliability
- Usability
- Efficiency
- Maintainability
- Portability

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC 25000 (SQuaRE) is most recent standard for software systems Which has a hierarchical model. 
[image]